# How do I make a function wait for the completion of another function before running

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem I'm facing is that I want to create a temporary work folder for a certain function to hold its assets and work on them. 
So:

```
await function someFunc() {
    createFolder()
    ...
    makeSomeFiles()
    doOtherStuff()
    ...
    deleteFolder()
}
```

But the functions that I am using, in node.js, are all async. Creating a folder is `fs.mkdir()` and deleting a folder is `fs.rmdir()` and downloading images and saving them is also an async procedure of some kind.

The problem is such: the folder gets created, and deleted, before any of the code in the middle executes. So I get errors from the middle section code that the folder doesn't exist, because it gets deleted prematurely. How do i make `fs.rmdir()`, at the end, wait for all the middle code to run first, before deleting the folder.

The specific code is this:

```
async function run() {
    //GENERATE SESSION ID AND FOLDER
    const sessionID = str.random(50);
    fs.mkdir('images/'+sessionID, (err) => {
        if (err) return err;
    });

    //DOWNLOAD IMAGE
    https.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#/media/File:RE_Kaja_Kallas.jpg', (file) => {
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('images/'+sessionID+'/image.jpeg'));
    });


    //CLEANUP
    fs.rmdir('images/'+sessionID, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        if (err) return err;
    });
}
```

Comment: async function someFunc() {
   await createFolder()
    ...
   await  makeSomeFiles()
   await doOtherStuff()
    ...
    await deleteFolder()
}

Comment: ... or use the Promises returned by the asynchronous node functions. That is a bit more code than using await, but can allow for some work do be done concurrently.

Comment: You have to properly write the internals of functions like `createFolder()` so that they either return a promise that resolves when the operations inside the function are done or you have to pass in a callback and the function  has to be designed to call that callback when everything is done.  You can't fix this from the outside.  You have to design the insides of these functions properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use promise-based versions of functions that do these operations and then use `async/await` with those promises:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
const got = require('got');

const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

async function run() {
     const sessionID = str.random(50);
     const dir = 'images/'+sessionID;
     await fsp.mkdir(dir);

     await pipeline(
         got.stream('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page#/media/File:RE_Kaja_Kallas.jpg'),
         fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/image.jpeg')
     );

     // not sure why you're trying to remove a directory that you just 
     // put a file in so it's not empty
     await fsp.rmdir(dir, { recursive: true })
}

run().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But, this function isn't making a lot of sense to me because you're creating a directory, downloading a file to it and then trying to remove a non-empty directory.

This uses the library `got()` for downloading the file because it's my goto library for http requests since it has both stream and promise interfaces.

Comment: Stream also has a `.promises`, you could use that instead of `util.promisify`

Comment: @ZacAnger - Yes, if you're running v15.  I wasn't willing to assume that quite yet, but that is a useful comment for people to see and know.

Comment: Oh, good point... I forget that not everyone runs the latest version all the time...

Comment: the reason why im deleting it later, is that i have code to do work on the image later on, and store the results somewhere else. So i want to create a temporary folder, download image, analyse it, store away the results elsewhere, delete folder

Comment: Question: as far as I'm aware, fs.rmdir and fs.mkdir are async. their sync counterparts are fs.rmdirSync and fs.mkdirSync. so what is the difference between fs.rmdir fs.mkdir and fsp.mkdir fps.rmdir. Aren't they both asynchronous?

Comment: @GeekOverdose - look at fs.promises.mkdir in the fs module documentation. It uses promises instead of plain callbacks and thus works with await.  It is asynchronous.